# SCOM Monitor not reporting

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2012, scom

I am running into a bit of an issue with SCOM. I have create the script below to monitor an application. It creates an entry in the Event log when the script runs and I have configured the alerts for a specific group in which the monitor is running on.

Am I not creating the script right is my question?

Here is an error that I got when I changed `oAPI.Return(oBag)` to `oAPI.ReturnItems`

> The process started at 2:24:23 PM failed to create
>   System.PropertyBagData. Errors found in output:
>
> C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager\Agent\Health Service
>   State\Monitoring Host Temporary Files 84\29451\voxwareMonitor.vbs(33,
>   2) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or
>   argument

```
Dim proc, serv, oArgs, oAPI, oBag

sComputerName = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputerName & "\root\cimv2")
sQueryPro = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"
sQuerySer = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Service"
Set objProcs = objWMIService.ExecQuery(sQueryPro)
Set objServ = objWMIService.ExecQuery(sQuerySer)

Set oAPI = CreateObject("MOM.ScriptAPI")
Set oBag = oAPI.CreatePropertyBag()

For Each objItem In objProcs
    If objItem.Name = "javaw.exe" Then
        proc = True
    End If
Next

For Each objS In objServ
    If objS.Name = "vlsoperatorconsole_voxwarevls" Then
        serv = True
    End If
Next

If proc = True And serv = True Then
    Call oBag.AddValue("Service", "Running")
    Call oBag.AddValue("Process", "Running")
    oAPI.LogScriptEvent "Voxware Monitor", 411, 0, "Application and Services are   running"
    Call oAPI.Return(oBag)
Else
    If proc = False Then
        Call oBag.AddValue("Process", "Stopped")
        oAPI.LogScriptEvent "Voxware Monitor", 911, 1, "Process has stopped"
        Call oAPI.Return(oBag)
    End If
    If serv = False Then
        Call oBag.AddValue("Service", "Stopped")
        oAPI.LogScriptEvent "Voxware Monitor", 911, 1, "Service has stopped"
        Call oAPI.Return(oBag)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Have you tried parentheses around the LogScriptEvent arguments?  `oAPI.LogScriptEvent("Voxware Monitor", 911, 1, "Process has stopped")`

Comment: @TonyHinkle -  Thank you for the reply, however, that's not the issue. I cannot get my SCOM server to respond. I wanted to know if my script is correct? if you run this under cscript it gives you the xml output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [MOMScriptAPI.ReturnItems Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd850161.aspx):

> The `ReturnItems` method submits objects to Operations Manager. For
>   this method to be successful, objects must have been previously added
>   to the in-memory array with `MOMScriptAPI.AddItem`.

Example:

```
Call oBag.AddValue("Service", "Running")
Call oBag.AddValue("Process", "Running")
oAPI.LogScriptEvent "Voxware Monitor", 411, 0, "Application and Services are   running"
'''Call oAPI.Return(oBag)
oAPI.AddItem oBag
Call oAPI.ReturnItems
```

Comment: That fixed my issue... it was the ReturnItems. It's now reading as a collection and not a single value. Thanks for pointing out the proper way of the the ReturnItems Method.